# Call Javascript function in Page load event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, pageload

I'm using ASP.NET 4. C#. Is there anyway to call a Javascript function or button click event in Page Load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use startup script with JavaScript or jquery

```
string script = "$(document).ready(function() {$('button').trigger('click'); });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call javascript function through asp.net button like,

By setting `OnClientClick` property to Javascript function name

or

you can write following in page_load event

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","return javascript:f1()");
```

If you want to call the Button click event in page_load event,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1_Click(sender,e);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "welcome";
        }
```

Hope this will work.